# Export cookies for all the pages visited on a website at the end

Tags: cookies, browser, firebug, web-testing

I need to visit all the pages on the production website fairly quickly (i cannot look at firebug and note down the value of cookie)and then at the end , at our order confirmation level, i need a tool that can tell me the cookies and value of cookies on each page of the website i visited. Is there any free tool that can help in that?

TIA

Comment: anyone has any input?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little wonky, but if you don't want to write something custom, you could use [SeleniumIDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/). I'm assuming (I don't have enough rep to comment yet to ask you) that you mean visit not "all the pages," but rather all the necessary pages to get to your order confirmation step.

If you needed to do that, you could just record yourself going through the steps using SeleniumIDE, then insert a storeCookie function after each page loads and write that out to a variable. Example:

```
[info] Executing: |storeCookie | cookieList | |
```

That would store all the cookies on the page, then you could echo them at the end.

```
[info] Executing: |echo | ${cookieList} | |
```

Not saying this is ideal -- I would write something in our Selenium WebDriver framework to do this, but if you want something standalone, you could try it.